# Comparison operators in Javascript

Tags: javascript, browser

Why when I run in Chrome console this snippets of code I get different results?

```
1 < 2 < 3
true

3 > 2 > 1
false
```

Comment: Because the check returns a boolean. And then the boolean is implicitly converted to a number for the next comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because programming is not math.

`1 < 2` returns boolean `true` which is then implicitly converted to a number `1` which is indeed less that three. Same thing happens in the second example but `1 > 1` returns `false`.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript doesn't support expressions like `0 < x < 10`. Because the `<` and `>` operators have equal precedence and are applied left to right, in effect what is being evaluated is `(1 < 2) < 3`.

Because the expression `(1 < 2)` evaluates to true, the second `<` operation is, in effect, evaluating whether `true` is less than or equal to `3`.

```
1 < 2 < 3
(1 < 2) < 3
true < 3
true
```

Your second example can be understood by applying the same procedure:

```
3 > 2 > 1
(3 > 2) > 1
true > 1
false
```

As for why `true < 3` evaluates to true and `true > 1` evaluates to false, the answer is a bit more complex, and has to do with the loose typing system in Javascript. In short, when compared with a number, javascript's `true` value evaluates to 1, and its' `false` value evaluates to 0.

This chapter on the substitution method of procedure application is fairly helpful. https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/sicp/book/node10.html

Comment: Note that JavaScript (and many other languages) act this way in part because they are descended from C, which has no boolean type. Typically in C programming (prior to the official boolean header file) one would use preprocessor directives to define `FALSE = 0` and `TRUE = 1`.